# Questions about installing spf13-vim on Windows

Tags: vim, spf13vim

i didn't know anything about vim untill yesterday except it's a text editor and today i installed gvim74 on my PC. i have git installed and and i created curl.cmd and verified via command line. but i didn't run spf13-vim-windows-install.cmd yet.

my questions;

1. is spf13-vim full vim distro so do i need to uninstall gvim before installing spf13-vim?
2. my installation path is on my D drive in a random folder. is it a problem for installation of spf13-vim? (if i don't need to uninstall gvim)
3. i already downloaded nerdtree, it works fine and spf13-vim also has nerdtree, should i uninstall it? (again if i don't need to uninstall gvim)

that's all for now.  I appreciate your help:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Spf13 is not a full Vim distribution: it's a collection of plugins and settings designed to make you feel comfortable and prevent you from actually learning to use Vim.

   You must have Vim installed on your machine for spf13 to work.
2. I don't know and SO is not the right place for such question. Use the plugin's issue tracker.
3. Yes, if you decide to install spf13 you can safely remove your previous nerdtree installation.

If you are new to Vim and serious about learning it I'd suggest you to forget about spf13, nerdtree or any plugin and start from scratch instead.

If you only want an usable and powerful text editor *right now*, don't bother with Vim and use Sublime Text.

Answer (score 3):

Most vim power users agree that "vim distributions" like spf are detrimental to learning Vim basics. They're an "easy start", but you end up depending too much on plugins without knowing what vim itself can do. I suggest you:

- stick to plain gVim
- learn Vim basics
- then, install NeoBundle
- and start reading other people's `.vimrc` for ideas
- and never, ever add anything into your own .vimrc that you haven't read and understood `:help` on.

EDIT: Brain fart, thought spf included Vim. As romainl says, it does not.